# No module named retro.import Open AI

Tags: python, openai-api

Im trying to run Open AI by importing a rom but whenever I run,

```
python3 -m pi /Users/"username"/Desktop/Sonic/Sonic\ The\ Hedgehog\ \(USA\,\ Europe\).md
```

it responds in saying that retro.import is not found.

Answer (score 0):

The module your looking for can be installed through

pip3 install gym-retro